# flask email not sending

Tags: python, flask

I using flask and need send email

my code for it

```
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message
#mail config
app.config['MAIL_SERVER'] = 'smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'mymail@gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'mypassword'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
mail = Mail(app)
```

"send" route

```
@app.route('/send/')
def send():
    msg = Message('Hi', sender = 'mymail@gmail.com', recipients = ['recipient@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = "This is the email body sending with flask!"
    mail.send(msg)
    #msg.html = '<b>HTML</b> body'
    return "Sent"
```

But after clicking on the above company I get the error

> TypeError: __init__() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given

```
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1836, in __call__
return self.wsgi_app(environ, start_response)
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1820, in wsgi_app
response = self.make_response(self.handle_exception(e))
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1403, in handle_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1817, in wsgi_app
response = self.full_dispatch_request()
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1477, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1381, in handle_user_exception
reraise(exc_type, exc_value, tb)
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\_compat.py", line 33, in reraise
raise value
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1475, in full_dispatch_request
rv = self.dispatch_request()
File "I:\python\lib\site-packages\flask\app.py", line 1461, in dispatch_request
return self.view_functions[rule.endpoint](**req.view_args)
File "G:\flask\fopster\hello.py", line 56, in send
msg = Message('Hi', sender = 'mymail@gmail.com', recipients = ['recipient@gmail.com'])
```

What could be the problem? The name of the mail addresses changed.

Comment: can you show your complete file ?

Comment: complete http://pastebin.com/dmp7Ur9N

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're instantiating your model Message class and not the flask mail Message class.

Do something like :

```
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message as MailMessage

@app.route('/send/')
def send():
    msg = MailMessage('Hi', sender = 'mymail@gmail.com', recipients = ['recipient@gmail.com'])
    msg.body = "This is the email body sending with flask!"
    mail.send(msg)
    #msg.html = '<b>HTML</b> body'
    return "Sent"
```

Comment: Could someone clarify for me about the sender and recipients? Cause I set a contact form which allowed the user send me an email, I tried few sets and it would email myself, but at the end I could really get the handle of it, like if I have an email and I want to receive email how would I set it up?

Answer (score 0):

try to append this after the imports

```
app=Flask(__name__)
```

You are not initialising the app.Go through this document [here](https://pythonhosted.org/Flask-Mail/) to learn in detail.

Comment: `from flask import Flask, redirect, render_template, session, url_for, flash
from flask.ext.wtf import Form
from flask.ext.sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from wtforms import StringField, SubmitField
from wtforms.validators import Required
from flask.ext.bootstrap import Bootstrap
from flask.ext.script import Manager
from flask.ext.script import Shell
from flask.ext.migrate import Migrate, MigrateCommand
from flask.ext.mail import Mail, Message
import os

app = Flask(__name__)`

everything is in place

Answer (score 0):

Check this.

```
from flask import Flask
from flask_mail import Mail, Message

app = Flask(__name__)

mail=Mail(app)

app.config['MAIL_SERVER']='smtp.gmail.com'
app.config['MAIL_PORT'] = 465
app.config['MAIL_USERNAME'] = 'your_email'
app.config['MAIL_PASSWORD'] = 'your_password'
app.config['MAIL_USE_TLS'] = False
app.config['MAIL_USE_SSL'] = True
app.config['MAIL_DEFAULT_SENDER'] = 'default_sender_email'
app.config['MAIL_ASCII_ATTACHMENTS'] = True
app.config['DEBUG'] = True

mail = Mail(app)

@app.route("/send")
def index():
    try:
        msg = Message('Subject', recipients = ['reciever_mail_id'])
        msg.body = "Hello Flask message sent from Flask-Mail"
        msg.html = "<b>TESTING HTML TAG</b>"
        mail.send(msg)
    except Exception as e:
        raise e
    return "Check Your Inbox !!!"

if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug = True)
```